# From ViewController navigate back to SWRevealViewController Front Page

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

[image: Navigation from view controller back to SWReveal Front Page]

As you can see in the picture, there're 3 controllers at the bottom which are (HomeTableViewController, NavigationViewController and NewsViewController)

HomeTableViewController is the Main Page which I'm using the SWRevealViewController and set it as a front page. (sw_front)

After I've selected a row in HomeTableViewController, it can navigate to NewsTableViewController. However, I've added a back button in the NewsViewController to navigate back to the previous page which is HomeTableViewController, I'm not manage to do that with this code.

In the HomeTableViewController navigate to NewsViewController by selected a row

```
@IBAction func btnBack(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let home = HomeTableViewController()
    self.presentViewController(home, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In the NewsViewController press back button back to previous page

```
@IBAction func btnBack(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let home = HomeTableViewController()
    self.presentViewController(home, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If I pressed the back button in the NewsViewController, this error appeared.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 200
```

This code has an error and is located in the HomeTableViewController.
I hope that someone could help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: how did you resolved it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `dismiss` the `presented` `viewController`:

```
@IBAction func btnBack(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let home = HomeTableViewController()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);
}
```

Comment: I still having the same problem, it shows the same error said that (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 200) Because the current view controller is not swrevealviewcontroller, and I need to back to sw_front, I couldn't do that

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are creating new `HomeTableViewController` in `btnBack` (and this new controller probably doesn't have `revealViewController`). There is no need to do this. You can just call `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:{});` as Islam Q. suggested:

```
@IBAction func btnBack(sender: AnyObject)
{
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);
}
```

Comment: I've delete the previous code and add your code in it, it doesn't have any respond, does I need to create any segue from NewsViewController to HomeTableViewController?

Comment: No, you should be ok without segue. Is there any chance that NewsViewController is pushed (via `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(...)`)? If so, than you need to pop it
`self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`

Comment: I cannot use pushViewController since I want to navigate back to TableView, so tableView is not applicable in this function. I've tried popToRootViewControllerAnimated, it cannot work as well, it has no any respond after I've clicked the back button.

Comment: Hm, ok, that you do need an unwind segue. Please see this answer as example on how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/973153

Comment: I'll try that on tomorrow because I've left my office.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/516#issuecomment-160590440
This solve my issue.
Delete the navigation controller between the Home and News Controller, and use the push Segue from Home to NewsViewController.